# Code Error 800A01A8 - Object Required

Tags: vbscript, hta

I have a HTA file that open a text box alows user to enter path to a folder then save it to a text file.

But when I trying to use second button to run a batch, it gives me an error code

### Code Error 800A01A8 - Object Required : Wscript

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Files Sync </title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Files Sync"
  ID="RY"
  VERSION="1.0"/>
</head>

<script language="vbscript">

Sub WriteTxt_OnClick()
    Dim fso, txt

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set txt = fso.CreateTextFile("\\fs-02\C$\ntfs3\scripts\MexSync\000.txt")

    txt.WriteLine document.Submitted_Link_To_Mex.body.value

    MsgBox "File Submitted",64,"Selection"


End Sub

Sub SYNC_onClick()

     Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
     WshShell.Run "cmd.exe /c C:\work\RLTP_SYNC_MEX\RunChangePS1.bat", 0
            ' 0 => hide
     MsgBox("Success")

End Sub



</script>


<H2>Copy And Paste The Folder Path To Here </H2>
<body>


<form name="Submitted_Link_To_Mex">
<textarea name="body" cols="150" rows="20">

</textarea>
</form>




<br>
    <input type="button" value="1. SUBMIT" name="WriteTxt"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="Button" value="2. SYNC" name="SYNC"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="Button" value="3. CLOSE" name="button2" onClick="close" class="button">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I can't find out why....did some research but no luck at all
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WScript object your line

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

tries to use does not exist in a HTA (it is provided by the w|cscript.exe hosts). As VBScript (the language itself) provides its own CreateObject function, just use

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a trailing `\` on your replacement text else you have `DataAppData`

```
Replace(txt, "K:\", "D:\Data\")
```

Also `response.write` is for ASP ...